# How to repeat the same button with SetterBar?

Tags: manipulate

I made a button using SetterBar. However, clicking the same button repeatedly does not apply. How to repeat the same button with SetterBar?

```
list={}; Manipulate[ list=Append[list,ele],{{ele,1},Range[5],SetterBar},TrackedSymbols:>{ele}]
```

The desired result is to use a SetterBar with duplicates like {1,5,5,3,3,4, ...}. Of course, you can substitute another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[list, 
 {{ele, 1}, Range[5], TrackingFunction -> (ele = #; AppendTo[list, ele]; &)},
 {{list, {ele}}, None}]
```

[image]